# Calculate values and export to csv from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, csv

In MySQL I have to following table

```
 ID     col1    
 1      234
 2      987
 3      544
```

I want to use Php to export this data to a .csv file as below

```
ID     col1    x     y
1      234   9891   18762
2      987   8763   37269
3      544   1852   86329
```

where values in x and y are the results from 2 functions using values from col1

```
function calX (col1){

}

function calY (col1){

}
```

from a post here I got the following code:

```
$connection = connectToDB();

$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";

$result = $connection->query($query);

if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');

$headers = $result->fetch_fields();

foreach ($headers as $header) {
     $head[] = $header->name;
}
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');

if ($fp && $result) {
   header('Content-Type: text/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
   header('Pragma: no-cache');
   header('Expires: 0');
   fputcsv($fp, array_values($head));
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
       fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
   }
   die;
}
```

how do I add the x and y columns?

Comment: Assuming these are PHP functions, access the variables using an array with array_values(in the while loop) and manipulate them. Another top would be to not use SELECT *, instead use the columns you want

Comment: I am new, not sure how to do that.

Comment: I've added an answer, also changed the select * query

Answer (score 1):

Based on your current code:

```
$connection = connectToDB();
$query = "SELECT id,col1 FROM mytable";
$result = $connection->query($query);
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$headers = $result->fetch_fields();
$i=0;
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $head[$i++] = $header->name;
}
$head[$i++]="x";
$head[$i]="y";
$csvrow = array();
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
   header('Content-Type: text/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
   header('Pragma: no-cache');
   header('Expires: 0');
   fputcsv($fp, array_values($head));
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
       //if there are more elements in row better do loop 
       $csvrow[0] = $row[0];
       $csvrow[1] = $row[1];
       $csvrow[2] = calX($row[0]);
       $csvrow[3] = calY($row[1]);
       fputcsv($fp, array_values($csvrow));
   }
   die;
}
```

The code I've edited can be optimised further as well.

Answer (score 0):

say both functions compute and return x and y values. i am rewriting your code

```
$connection = connectToDB();
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$result = $connection->query($query);
if (!$result) die('Couldn\'t fetch records');
$headers = $result->fetch_fields();
$i=0;
foreach ($headers as $header) {
    $head[$i++] = $header->name;
}
$head[$i++]="x";
$head[$i]="y";
$csvrow = array();
$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
if ($fp && $result) {
   header('Content-Type: text/csv');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
   header('Pragma: no-cache');
   header('Expires: 0');
   fputcsv($fp, array_values($head));
   while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
       //if there are more elements in row better do loop 
       $csvrow[0] = $row[0];
       $csvrow[1] = $row[1];
       $csvrow[2] = functionCalX($row[1]); 
       //add Y also , also do typechecking if needed
       fputcsv($fp, array_values($csvrow));
   }
   die;
}
```

i edited the same code, it can be optimized. I am not that familiar with php

Answer (score 0):

its hard to say without seeing the functions 
$sumxy = $x + $y;

echo $sumxy;

also here is the link for the docs for the csv export
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php